# DataSet select parent rows where child rows contains x value

Tags: c#, linq, dataset, datarelation

I have two `DataTables` in a `DataSet` linked together by a `DataRelation` and I'm trying to select all parent rows that have a child row with value x.

The parent table contains products and the child table contains categories that the product is in.

```
DataSet dsProducts = new DataSet();

DataTable dtProducts = new DataTable("products");
dtProducts.Columns.Add("entity_id", typeof(int));
dtProducts.Columns.Add("sku", typeof(string));
dtProducts.Columns.Add("mpn", typeof(string));
dtProducts.Columns.Add("brand", typeof(string));
dtProducts.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
dtProducts.Columns.Add("description", typeof(string));
dtProducts.Columns.Add("short_description", typeof(string));
dtProducts.Columns.Add("image", typeof(string));
dtProducts.Columns.Add("weight", typeof(double));
dtProducts.Columns.Add("qty", typeof(double));
dtProducts.Columns.Add("cost", typeof(double));
dtProducts.Columns.Add("price", typeof(double));
dtProducts.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dtProducts.Columns["entity_id"] };
dsProducts.Tables.Add(dtProducts);

DataTable dtCategories = new DataTable("categories");
dtCategories.Columns.Add("entity_id", typeof(int));
dtCategories.Columns.Add("category_id", typeof(int));
dsProducts.Tables.Add(dtCategories);

dsProducts.Relations.Add(new DataRelation("entity_id", dtProducts.Columns["entity_id"], dtCategories.Columns["entity_id"]));
```

---

**EDIT**

I've pieced together this piece of Linq code which works but seems pointless having a `DataRelation`

```
var rows = from prods in dsProducts.Tables["products"].AsEnumerable()
            join cats in dsProducts.Tables["categories"].AsEnumerable() on prods.Field<int>("entity_id") equals cats.Field<int>("entity_id")
            where cats.Field<int>("category_id") == id
            select prods;
```

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question if your answer works for you.

Comment: it works but it seems a bit stupid to have to recreate a relation when there is already a relation there.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
DataRow[] rows = dsProducts.Tables["products"].Select("entity_id=" + id);
```

instead of:

```
DataRow[] rows = dsProducts.Tables["products"].Select("Child(entity_id).category_id = " + id);
```

Because you already create relation between two table with common column "entity_id",so as long as you entity_id is matched, you get your desired result.

Comment: that will bring back all the products with that entity_id. Im looking for a rowset of products who are only in a particular category

Answer (score 0):

```
DataRelation relation = dsProducts.Relations.Add(new DataRelation("entity_id", dtProducts.Columns["entity_id"], dtCategories.Columns["entity_id"]));

DataRow[] childRows = dsProducts.Tables["categories"].Select("category_id=" + id);
foreach (DataRow row in childRows) {
   DataRow[] parentRows = row.GetParentRows(relation); // parentRows[0] should be your parent
}
```

Comment: Shouldnt it be categories for the childrows `DataRow[] childRows = dsProducts.Tables["categories"]` and relation should be `entity_id`